# MySQL: Create multiple tables with one query

Tags: mysql, syntax

Can you list multiple table names in a MySQL `CREATE TABLE` query?

```
CREATE TABLE table1, table2, table3 LIKE table_template;
```

If so, can you do it with the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1, table2, table3 LIKE table_template;
```

---

I know you can do this with `DROP TABLE`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1, table2, table3;
```

The [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-table.html) for `DROP TABLE` explicitly show that you enter a string of names:

```
DROP [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF EXISTS]
    tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
    [RESTRICT | CASCADE]
```

---

The [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) for `CREATE TABLE` don't show a table name string:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]

More Syntax Variations ...
```

Can anyone point me to a reference that states explicitly that multiple tables can or can't be created with one query?

I searched the [CREATE TABLE Syntax doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) for "string", "tbl_name", and "names", but no luck.

Comment: It's not possible to create multiple tables in a single query... Still not sure why you need more than one table... Using 1=2 makes sure that no rows are returned (this would actually copy content of table1 to table2 otherwise). Code will be the same when creating more than one table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the docs, it looks like you can't create multiple tables with one `CREATE`. You *can* use `IF NOT EXISTS` and `LIKE` together, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 LIKE table_template;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 LIKE table_template;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table3 LIKE table_template;
```

Here's the page from the MySQL docs: [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Comment: Everything in your answer is in my question. I asked if anyone could point me to a reference that explicitly states whether or not multiple tables can be created with one query.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that when I read the question.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I expect that someone will find the info you posted useful when searching for an answer.

Comment: @codewaggle The reference you are looking for is in the CREATE TABLE syntax (that you have linked in your question.) It states *`CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] **tbl_name** (create_definition,...) [table_options] [partition_options]`* That's only one tbl_name, not a list of tables.